# $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^p(xy)\log(x^2+y^2)}{x}$ when $p>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

It seems the limit exists (I can't find a subset for which it doesn't) and it is $0$, but I don't know how to prove it.

EDIT: the hint helped me a lot. However, I solved it in a little different way, I hope it's alright. We have:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^p(xy)\log(x^2+y^2)}{x} = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\sin^p(xy)}{xy} \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}y\log(x^2+y^2)$$
The first limit goes to $0$ by L'Hôpital (supposing $p>1$) and the second goes to $0$ by polar coordinates, so the solution is $0$. Is it OK?

Comment: What have you deduced from the given hint? It should be fine if you could add your thoughts about that editing your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{\sin^p(xy) \log(x^2+y^2)}{x}=\frac{\sin^p(xy)}{(xy)^p}\, (x^{p-1}y^p)\log(x^2+y^2)$$

and by polar coordinates

$$(x^{p-1}y^p)\log(x^2+y^2)=2r^{2p-1}\log r \cdot(\cos^{p-1}\theta \cdot \sin^p \theta)$$